# Installing mongodb as node module fails on mac

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, kerberos, bcrypt

I am trying to install mongodb as npm dependency on OS X 10.10.3 , and when compiling bcrypt I encounter following error:

```
> bcrypt@0.8.5 install /Users/alex/Projects/frontend/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bcrypt_lib.node
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/bcrypt_lib.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit        (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.10.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/alex/Projects/frontend/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v5.10.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
frontend@0.0.2 /Users/alex/Projects/frontend
 ├── bcryptjs@2.3.0  extraneous
 └── kerberos@0.0.19  extraneous
```

UPD: I've found related problem solution https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2933

Comment: ls /usr/lib/ | grep libstdc++ exec this commend and tel me what it gave you ?

Comment: @ZeRubeus → ls /usr/lib/ | grep libstdc++
      libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib
      libstdc++.6.dylib
      libstdc++.dylib

Comment: execute this (locate libstdc++.so) and tel me the output

Comment: @ZeRubeus : → locate libstdc++.so

WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.

Comment: @ZeRubeus after creating it, output is still empty